# AChartEngine add second series

Tags: android, achartengine

I have a simple TimeChart in AChartEngine, everything works good but i have no idea how to add second series. Every my try was ended by ANR. Have you got any ideas how to add another series? This is my code:

EDIT: I changed code, i tried add second line but i have ANR:

```
public class TestgrafActivity extends Activity {
private XYMultipleSeriesDataset mDataset;
private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer;
List<double[]> values = new ArrayList<double[]>();
private GraphicalView mChartView;
private TimeSeries time_series,time_series2;


private LinearLayout layout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart);

    time_series = new TimeSeries("Temperature");
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
        long value = new Date().getTime();
        time_series.add(new Date(value+(i*1000)), new Random().nextInt(25));

    } 

    time_series2 = new TimeSeries("Temperature2");
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
        long value = new Date().getTime();
        time_series2.add(new Date(value+(i*1000)), new Random().nextInt(40));

    } 


    mDataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    mDataset.addSeries(time_series);
    mDataset.addSeries(time_series2);

    XYSeriesRenderer r = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    r.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    r.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
    r.setFillPoints(true);
    r.setLineWidth(3);
    r.setDisplayChartValues(true);

    XYSeriesRenderer r2 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    r2.setColor(Color.RED);
    r2.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
    r2.setFillPoints(true);
    r2.setLineWidth(3);
    r2.setDisplayChartValues(true);

    mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(r2);


    mRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(16);
    mRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
    mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
    mRenderer.setLegendTextSize(15);
    mRenderer.setPointSize(3f);
    mRenderer.setPanEnabled(true, true);
    mRenderer.setZoomEnabled(true, true);


    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(r2);
    mRenderer.setClickEnabled(true);
    mRenderer.setSelectableBuffer(20);
    mRenderer.setPanEnabled(true);       
    mRenderer.setChartTitle("Temperature");
    mRenderer.setXTitle("Time");
    mRenderer.setYTitle("Degrees C");
    mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
    mRenderer.setZoomEnabled(true);
    mRenderer.setXLabels(12);
    mRenderer.setYLabels(10);
    mRenderer.setShowGrid(true);
    mRenderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
    mRenderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);


    mChartView = ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(this, mDataset, mRenderer,
            "HH:mm:ss");

    layout.addView(mChartView);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only one Series in this code. Where is the code where you try to add another series?

The general approach is this:

```
mDataset.addSeries(0, time_series);
mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(0, time_renderer);
//...
//...
mDataset.addSeries(1, some_other_series);
mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(1, some_other_renderer);
//...
//...
```

Comment: 1) It looks like you are adding r2 twice (which means there are 3 seriesrenderers but only 2 datasets). Try fixing that. 2) It would really help pin-point the error if you provided the exception capture from LogCat

Comment: It was over a year ago that I worked on this .. but IIRC, the pan worked only if the chart data was larger than what fits on one screen. I can't be sure of it though.